# Dialogflow button postback handling

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a fulfillment webhook that returns a card as a rich text message. The cards have buttons, the buttons have postback values.

When testing with dialogflow console, the buttons show, they are clicked, and nothing happens. Dialogflow does not send the result back to my webhook or really try to do anything else.

My suspicion is that it is the client's job to handle those click events and the console client does not have this implemented.  Something to this?  Or is there another explanation?

Comment: Have you found a solution? This is something I'm trying to understand too